# How to Open launcher application on mailto function in href link using php

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html

How to always ask for choose launcher application in mailto function without give permission in browser using php
When i have click on link then always ask for choose launcher. How can i set using php code

I have set below code

```
<a href="mailto:jiteshgondaliya@gmail.com">Click Here</a>
```

Comment: you cant do this by `PHP`. `JS` might help you on the client side.

Comment: Have you any idea how can i implement??

Comment: it will open the default application.

Comment: i know but we have need to open from code

Comment: If you are just serving up a web page, the mailto: link is the best you can do.  You will not get permission to launch an app for the user automatically.

Answer (score 1):

Which application to be used for handling `mailto:` type of links do not depend on your code, but on the way the user configured their own browser.

This is something that is 100% in the users power. It depends how they prefer to send their emails.
You can not manipulate the default email client for the user, as you can not choose the browser that the user will use to view your page.

If you tell us more about your specific use case maybe we will be able to help you more.

Comment: Is is possible browser configuration from code 
Thanks,

Comment: Changing a user's options/configuration browser-wise is something along the lines of malware.

Comment: @jitesh The companies that produce browsers are spending millions to make sure that nobody except the user can change the configuration! Check: http://www.forbes.com/sites/andygreenberg/2013/01/28/google-offers-3-14159-million-in-total-rewards-for-chrome-os-hacking-contest/

Comment: Thank you for giving such a information. We have need to find some another solution. tell me if any solution thanks

Comment: @jitesh As I wrote: `If you tell us more about your specific use case maybe we will be able to help you more.`

Comment: @Antoan: Have you any idea related change Browser Configuration for mailto: functions